# how to calculate cache misses?

Tags: caching, memory-management, operating-system, paging, mmu

***I  got the following question:***

A and B are arrays of 4 integers (integer = 4 bytes = one word) on a computer that uses a cache with cache size of 64 Bytes, and with block size of one word. 
A starts in address 0 and B starts in address 16
Assume the cache is initially empty.

A user run the following code:

```
for (i=0; i<2; i++) 
{
    for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
         read A[j]
         read B[j]
    }
}
```

> ***I'm asked to answer&explain how many cache misses would you expect at the following cases:***
>
> a)    The cache uses direct mapping.
>
> b)    The cache uses 2-Way Set Associativity

What does it mean that 'A starts in address 0 and B starts in address 16'? don't sure how to access this question

Answer (score 1):

It's saying:

```
&A[0] == 0
&B[0] == 16
```